# Issues in creating Queue Managers from Web Sphere 5.3 on Windows7

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-x64, ibm-mq

I installed IBM MQ Version 5.3 on 64bits Windows7 computer, then i tried to create a Queue Manager using Web Sphere MQ Explorer. It is always popping up the the below error message when i create queue manager. 
Can anyone please tell me the reason? Is IBM MQ 5.3 is not supported with Windows7?

> Unable to create queue manager qm.

[image: Error message popped up when creating a Queue Manger]

Answer (score 1):

No ... MQ 5.3 not supported on Windows 7 as per http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27006285

Answer (score 1):

WMQ v5.3 went out of support in 2006 (a long time before Windows 7 was released).  Why in the world are you trying to install obsolete software?  You need to be installing WMQ v7.5 (or v7.1) on Windows 7.

Comment: This was needed for the migration testing